# Proper use of Dispatch to show activity indicator during a long task

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

During a computationally intensive task, I wish to show the user an activity indicator. What is the best way to do this?

My task (contrived of course), lasts a couple of seconds:

```
func startThinking(howMany: Int) {
    for i in 0...howMany {
        let p:Double = Double(i)
        let _ = p / Double.pi
    }

    delegate?.finishedThinking()
}
```

This is called on a button tap:

```
@IBAction func startTap(_ sender: Any) {
    Thinker.sharedInstance.startThinking(howMany: 500000000)
    myActivity.startAnimating()
}
```

And stopped when the *thinking* task is finished:

```
func finishedThinking() {
    print ("finished thinking")
    myActivity.stopAnimating()
}
```

But the activity indicator is not showing up; the UI is blocked by the difficult thinking task.

I've tried putting the `startAnimating` on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myActivity.startAnimating()
}
```

or the difficult task onto its own thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    Thinker.sharedInstance.startThinking(howMany: 500000000)
}
```

and various other combinations that I've run across in Stack. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would move the call to start animating to before the thinker call, and verify that it works if you don't start thinking. You also need to stop the animation from the main thread.

```
@IBAction func startTap(_ sender: Any) {
    myActivity.startAnimating()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        Thinker.sharedInstance.startThinking(howMany: 500000000)
    }
}

func finishedThinking() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        myActivity.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

I adjusted a few things:

- moved the `.startAnimating()` call to be first. It is already on the main thread since it was called from the interface
- specify the `qos` as `.userInitiated`
- run the `.stopAnimating()` on the main thread

Comment: Hmm, that was straight-forward. Thank you. Leaving the `qos` option out works as well.